# How to use Telegram Kit on iPhone

Tags: iphone, sdk, telegram

I need to integrate the Telegram Chat on my application but I have the problems with the downloaded code.
Can someone help me with tutorial or another info?
Thanks

Comment: Post your code for help. Provide descriptions and examples of the errors.

Comment: Hi,I download the telegram package and I look two directory: Telegraph end TelegraphKit. I use the TelegraphKit static library without success. I integrate the project ( Telegraph directory ) in my project but I dont't look the project header file. Thanks